Calculating the correlation coefficient of time series data of unqual length
Suppose you have a dataframe like this
data = {'site': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'item': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
         'date': ['2023-03-01', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-20', '2023-03-27', '2023-03-5', '2023-03-12'],
         'quantity': [10,20,30, 20, 30, 50]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_sample.head()

Where you have different sites and items with a date and quantity. Now, what you want to do is calculate the correlation between say site A and site B for item x and their associated quantity. Although, they could be of different length in the dataframe. How would you go about doing this.
The actual data in consideration here can be found here here.
Now, what I tried was just setting up two different dataframes like this
df1 = df_sample[(df_sample['site'] == 'A']) & (df_sample['item'] == 'x')]
df2 = df_sample[(df_sample['site'] == 'B']) & (df_sample['item'] == 'x')]

then just force them to have the same size, and calculate the correlation coefficient from there but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Correlation measures how closely two variables change together in a linear fashion. This concept doesn't apply to categorical variables.

@iBeMeltin Sorry, should of clarified (edited now), I am trying to get the correlation coefficient by quantity.

Do you want to consider the date as the variable to align the datasets? It would be best to provide the exact expected output.

Reshape to wide form with pivot_table and add zeros to missing data points, this will allow a correct comparison. You can then select the item you want and compute the correlation of all combinations of columns with corr:
tmp = df_sample.pivot_table(index='date', columns=['item', 'site'],
                            values='quantity', fill_value=0)

out = tmp['x'].corr()

Output:
site         A         B         C
site                              
A     1.000000 -0.449618 -0.442627
B    -0.449618  1.000000 -0.464363
C    -0.442627 -0.464363  1.000000

Intermediate tmp:
item           x            
site           A     B     C
date                        
2023-03-01  10.0   0.0   0.0
2023-03-10  20.0   0.0   0.0
2023-03-12   0.0   0.0  50.0
2023-03-20   0.0  30.0   0.0
2023-03-27   0.0  20.0   0.0
2023-03-5    0.0   0.0  30.0


You can align data by filtering each site's entries setting the date as index and then finding a=common dates
for example:
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
data = {'site': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'item': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
        'date': ['2023-03-01', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-20', '2023-03-27', '2023-03-05', '2023-03-12'],
        'quantity': [10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 50]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_sample['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['date'])

# Filter data for sites A and B for item x
df_a = df_sample[(df_sample['site'] == 'A') & (df_sample['item'] == 'x')].set_index('date')['quantity']
df_b = df_sample[(df_sample['site'] == 'B') & (df_sample['item'] == 'x')].set_index('date')['quantity']

# Align data by common dates only
common_dates = df_a.index.intersection(df_b.index)
df_a = df_a.loc[common_dates]
df_b = df_b.loc[common_dates]

# Combine and calculate correlation
df_combined = pd.DataFrame({'A': df_a, 'B': df_b})
if len(df_combined) < 2:
    print("Not enough overlapping data for correlation calculation.")
else:
    correlation = df_combined.corr().loc['A', 'B']
    print("Correlation coefficient between site A and site B:", correlation)

Hope this helps.

What if df_a and df_b are different shapes? Wouldnt we still need to make them the same?

If df_a and df_b are of different lengths, there’s no need to make them the same size manually. By aligning them with common_dates = df_a.index.intersection(df_b.index), we’re automatically selecting only the dates that both series share. This results in df_a and df_b being trimmed to the same set of dates without padding with arbitrary values, which would affect the correlation. After alignment, we can calculate the correlation based on these overlapping dates.
